# How to use Ionic2 with Angular2.0.0 stable version?

Tags: angular, ionic2

I've setup ionic2 project. But it uses **Angular2.0.0-rc.4**. 
As **2.0.0-rc.5** has major changes like `NgModule` and as now Angular2 is stable.

So is there any way to use **Ionic2** with stable **Angular2** ?

Answer (score 1):

The new ionic 2 version is out. You need to update it to the ionic 2 RC0 which uses angular 2 final.

Answer (score 0):

You can't, you have to wait for Ionic to update their project to final themselves, before you can use ng2 final.